# How do I change the Form Processor "Edit Action" Form?

Tags: forms, form-processor

I want to change a small thing in the graphical user interface which allows to change a form processor (/civicrm/admin/automation/formprocessor/...).
Specifically, I want to change the form that appears when I create or edit an Action.

I want to add a field where users are able to write a default string. This string should be written inside a CiviCRM custom field, if there is no other value. So, this field should work similarly to the `Default Subject` field in the `Configuration` section.

The reason for this: I have an Input field of type `Option Group` that hands an array of products to the Actions. For each available product, I want to create an Action testing if the input array contains this product. If yes, a new Activity should be created, with the custom field `product type` filled with a default string (name of product).

Right now, this custom field is already part of the `Create Action` form, but it has a dropdown menue allowing me to auto-fill the field. But I don't want to choose anything from the dropdown menue (like Input fields, for example). Instead I want to be able to write some default string there.

I didn't find any similar question/thread, and poking around in the code at `/public/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/form-processor/` doesn't seem to bring me further.

Also, I cannot use the `Retrieval of defaults` tab, because I do not want any Input field filled by default. The default value will only come into the game if the Condition of one Activity (that is, `Array contains...`) is fulfilled.

Where is this form created? Where can I change the field type of specific (custom) fields?

Any hint is appreciated :)

**Edit**: It would also solve the problem to have an array-type input field, and an `Explode List` Action that actually takes an array, and properly and accessibly outputs all of its values (e.g. via indices). I don't really understand why Formprocessor Extension has all different types of option groups, but no *simple* array, and none that actually works with `Explode List`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the "Other: Set Value" action.  Add the condition on this field, and use that action's output to populate the custom field.

Form Processor works on objects, not strings, so it wouldn't work to have a string that isn't generated by another action or input.